# IOS code has become very slow because of objc_msgSend

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, arrays

I have rewritten part of my code from very simple c arrays to using (or trying to use) objects in order to get more structure into it. Instead of passing arrays through the function header I am now using a global array defined by a singleton. You can see an example of a function in my code below:

it was:

```
void calcdiv(int nx,int ny,float **u,float **v,
float **divu,float dx,float dy,float **p,
float dt,float rho, float **bp,float **lapp)
{

int i,j;

for (i=2;i<=nx-3;++i){
    for (j=2;j<=ny-3;++j){
        divu[i][j] = (u[i+1][j]-u[i-1][j])*facu +
                     (v[i][j+1]-v[i][j-1])*facv;
    }
}
...
```

now it is:

```
void calcdiv()
{

int i,j;

SingletonClass* gV = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];

for (i=2;i<=gV.nx-3;++i){
    for (j=2;j<=gV.ny-3;++j){
        gV.divu[i][j] = (gV.u[i+1][j]-gV.u[i-1][j])*facu +
                        (gV.v[i][j+1]-gV.v[i][j-1])*facv;
    }
}
...
```

Before the restructuring I have been using the function call as given above. That means passing the pointers to the arrays directly. Now I access the arrays by the singleton call "SingletonClass* gV...". It works very fine except the fact that it is much slower than before. The profiler tells me that my program spends 41% of the time with objc_msgSend which I have not had before.

From reading through the posts I have understood that this probably can happen when msgSend is called very often. This is then most likely the case here, because my program needs a lot of number crunching in order to display an animated flow with OpenGl.

This leads me to my question: What would you suggest? Should I stay with my simple C implementation or is there a rather simple way to accelerate the objective c version? Please be patient with me since I am new to objective c programming.

Any hints and recommendations are greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Factor out the property accesses.  While you're at it you can factor out one layer of array access.

Comment: You've got `(nx-5) * (ny-5)` accesses to divu, and twice that many to u and v.  Factor those out of the loops, assigning references to divu, u, and v to temps.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am Not sure if i completely understand. Could You give an example?

Comment: You already did it, in the first code sample.  Just assign your divu, u, v, and factu variables from the singleton before entering the loops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your straight C method works fine, and your Objective C method puts you at a disadvantage due to method calling, and you need the performance, then there's no reason not to use straight C.  From looking at your code, I don't see any advantage to whatever "structure" you're adding, because the working code looks almost precisely the same.  In other words, Obj-C doesn't buy you anything here, but straight C does, so go with what's best for your user, because in terms of maintainability and readability, there's no difference in the two implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. It is true for this code. My idea was to put loops like in the example in methods later on. For example for general vector or matrix operations. Maybe it is faster then?

Comment: The only way you can really tell is to measure the performance that you get from it. You also have to test a release version because the debug options are set to turn off optimization to enable single stepping in the debugger.  In truth, Objective C is a superset of C, so you shouldn't feel, even from a language purist point of view, that there was anything wrong with what you're doing.  Back in the old days, we'd write in C and write the high performance code in assembler.  Not too many people writing at the machine level these days, and C appears to give you good performance.

Comment: thanks again. I used to program Fortran 77 in order to get good performance on HPC computers... but C certainly performs similarly.